# Действие в default-контроллере модуля в Yii2 без указания default в url

Tags: php, yii2, маршрутизация, default

Имеется такая файловая структура модуля `todo` в Yii2:

```
/modules
  /todo
    /controllers
      DefaultController.php
    /views
      /default
        index.php
        add-item.php
```

В **DefaultController.php** есть `actionIndex` и `actionAddItem`. Проблема с маршрутизацией. По адресу `site.com/todo` подхватывается `DefaultController::actionIndex()` - все ок. Но при запросе `site.com/todo/add-item` возвращается 404. А если запросить `site.com/todo/default/add-item`, то все тоже ок.

Я так и не пойму, это нормальное поведение?

В любом случае, мне нужен именно вариант с `site.com/todo/add-item`, где ищется actionAddItem в **default** контроллере, если не находит соответствующего `AddItemController::actionIndex()`. Как это сделать?

```php
namespace app\modules\todo\controllers;

class DefaultController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionAddItem($parent = null, $group = null) { /* ... */ }
    public function actionIndex($id) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Конфиг urlManager:

```php
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'enableStrictParsing' => false,
  'rules' => [
    // Был такой немного костыльный вариант, но тогда, если добавить другой
    // контроллер рядом и прописать в нем actionIndex,
    // например GroupController::actionIndex(), то адрес вида site.com/todo/group
    // воспринимается как group - это действие в DefaultController, а это не то. 

    // '<module>/<action>' => '<module>/default/<action>'
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Я так и не пойму, это нормальное поведение?

Да, это нормальное поведение, так работает роутинг в Yii2.

Можно добавить роут, в котором конкретно указать, для какого модуля и действий применять это правило. Пример:

```
'urlManager' => [
    ...
    'rules' => [
        '<module:todo>/<action:(add-item)>' => '<module>/default/<action>'
    ],
],
```

В `<action>` можно указать несколько значений, в `<module>` и `<controller>` - тоже. Больше примеров в документации: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/runtime-routing#parameterizing-routes

Answer (score 0):

> Я так и не пойму, это нормальное поведение?

Конечно. Ведь вы обращаетесь: `имяМодуля/имяКонтроллера/имяМетода`. Просто для метода `index` указывать его в урле не обязательно.

> В любом случае, мне нужен именно вариант с site.com/todo/add-item, где ищется actionAddItem в default контроллере, если не находит соответствующего AddItemController::actionIndex(). Как это сделать?

Надо прописать маршрутизацию. Например в  `urlManager` по стандартным правилам или в методе `bootstrap` (тоже по стандартным правилам менеджера), предварительно реализовав `BootstrapInterface`

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module implements BootstrapInterface {

    public function bootstrap($app) {
        $url = $this->moduleUrl ? $this->moduleUrl : $this->id;

        $app->getUrlManager()->addRules(
            [

                $url => $this->id . '/default/index',               
                $url . '/<action:(add-item)>' => $this->id . '/default/<action>', // <--- вот это               
            ],
            false
        );
    }

}
```